# jQuery multiselect dropdown values hidden behind modal pop up scrollable section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used Jquery multiselect dropdown and set fix height of modal body for scrollable section. The problem is multiselect dropdown is hiding behind that scrollable section and I want to show it on top of scrollable part.

Check the screenshot below please:

[image]

Html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="multiChkLbl required">Biological measures</label>
    <select id="multiChkBioMasures" class="form-control" name="bioMasures" multiple="multiple" value="${IdentifierData.identifier66}">
        <option value="Density">Density</option>
        <option value="Abundance">Abundance</option>
        <option value="Size">Size</option>
        <option value="Distribution/home range">Distribution/home range</option>
        <option value="Biodiversity">Biodiversity</option>
        <option value="Food web/energetics">Food web/energetics</option>
        <option value="Recruitment">Recruitment</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS: Modal scrollable part height set like this

```
height: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

jquery: On load

```
$("#multiChkBioMasures").multiselect();
```

Comment: The solution is probably mostly CSS and maybe some JS, but please create a [mcve].

Comment: yes, it'll be easy for us to notify the issue quickly, at least provide JsFiddle, Codepen links.

Comment: @Chris G and Lakshman Kambam I have created JSFiddle for the mentioned issue. Please find link for JSFiddle is : https://jsfiddle.net/bg1wy5eo/28/

Comment: Here's a quick fix: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9L76mjgp/ (I simply added padding) There's fast and good solution to this I can see; the only thing that comes to mind is to move the `<ul>` that pops up to `<body>` so it appears above the fixed modal; this also requires positioning it manually.

Answer (score 0):

use this below class to adjust your multi-select container, you know the height of your modal as per that height you can give top position pixel.

.multiselect-container
{
  position:fixed !important
  top:0px !important 
  left:50px !important
}